# LCR circuit at resonance

Tags: electrical-resistance, capacitance, resonance, inductance

I am studying about the LCR circuit and have a question regarding potential difference across inductor and capacitor.

From the thing I have studied I came to know about that potential across inductor leads current by phase of π/2 and potential across capacitor lags by π/2. So the potential across inductor and capacitor differ by a phase of π.

My question is at resonance when current is in phase of applied ac potential, the potential across inductor and capacitor cancels each other and potential across resistor is same as that of applied ac voltage, **what would be the potential difference at inductor and capacitor as a function of time?**

Comment: Do you know complex numbers? If you do, you can calculate all such circuits with the complex impedance for capacitors $Z_C={1\over{i\omega C}}$ and inductors $Z_L=i\omega L$ just like you would calculate them with ohmic resistors, i.e. using Kirchhoff's laws. If you don't know complex numbers, yet, this is a very good time to learn the basics.